# Running bitcoin core in a low storage system

Tags: bitcoind, pruning

I have a machine with ~40GB in storage. The Bitcoin block chain is ~75GB in size, is there any chance to run bitcoind in my system? I mean, can I somehow skip downloading some part of the block chain?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot skip downloading the blockchain, but you can skip storing it.

If you run Bitcoin Core with the `-prune=N` or put `prune=N` in the bitcoin.conf file, only at most N megabytes worth of blocks will be stored on disk. N has to be at least 550 currently.

Pruning does not reduce the validation or security at all, but does prevent your node from serving historical blocks to other peers.

Comment: But are the latest blocks downloaded this way?

Comment: All blocks are still downloaded and verified like before. They're just not kept on your disk forever.

Comment: @PieterWuille: Do you perhaps know the answer to this follow-up question? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52030/what-happens-if-you-set-prune-n-to-a-value-between-0-and-550