# How can i run own web wallet without no need Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, wallet, website-integration, raspberry-pi

I have a simple web bitcoin wallet script. I know JSON-RPC connections and others. Maybe after My script can be mini bitcoin gambling...
But i want to learn that;

I want host everything in my raspberry pi. But blockchain datas is very big. How can run my web wallet without blockchain on my host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/how-can-i-run-bitcoind-in-pruning-mode)

Comment: I honestly dont advice to run bitcoind on a raspberry pi, it will be extemely slow. you could get a vps for a couple $ at ovh.com or digitalocean.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a wallet, [Bolt](https://vladimirtahl.github.io/bolt/#), which does not require a downloaded blockchain. (It queries blockchain.info to find the balance of addresses.)

It do all his job on front end without any bitcoin core installed.

And uses api like blockchain.info to send transactions