# I have Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 (64-bit) and I can't get prune to work

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning

First I close Bitcoin Core...

The size of Bitcoin Core it is 105GB and I want to do pruning so I can have only 2 GB. I make a notepad file named `bitcoin.conf` and then I write inside `prune=2000` or I even tried `prune=<2000>`.

Then, I have put this file at the install directory or I created the folder Bitcoin and I have put the notepad file in there at the path `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin`

After all these I open the Bitcoin Core, but nothing happens, it still is 105 GB.

What I am doing wrong? Please help me, I can't understand!

[image]

Comment: Where did you place `bitcoin.conf` file? Can you check your `debug.log` (should be in the same directory)? Also `-prune=2000` will not result in a 2GB datadir-size, more 4GB because the UTXO set and header-index will take up some space too. Lowest possible size is `-prune=550`.

Comment: I have uploaded a pic that you can see they are in the same folder and I have opened the notepad file I created to see what I have written inside. What am I doing wrong Jonas? Thx in advance!

Comment: related: [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406)

Comment: @JonasSchnelli: Do you know when the pruning would start? Would it be immediately after startup or only e.g. when the next block is added? (See comment on my answer for context.)

Comment: Generally is there anyone that succesfully pruned with Bitcoin Core??? So he can tell us the procedure step by step... Please...

Comment: Pruning is simple, just add `-prune=550` to your startup arguments. If you have already synced and verified the chain, it will immediately (at startup) prune the chain.

Comment: Thx Jonas for your answer!!! Yes I have already synced the chain, could you please explain me where are the startup arguments at Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1):

If you put startup commands on the command line, you need to add a dash in the beginning (e.g. `bitcoind -prune=2000`).

However, when you put them in the `bitcoin.conf`, I think they have to be put without a dash (e.g. `prune=2000`). Yet, in the screenshot you show it has a dash. Have you tried putting it in the `bitcoin.conf` without the dash?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and without dash... What should be happening if the prune command works? I mean the 105GB would disappear instantly? I don't know what to do more so I can prune... if anyone can think something is welcomed!

Comment: Not sure, sorry. It should at the latest trigger with the next block discovered though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right there in your screenshot. You have not actually created the `bitcoin.conf`. It should not be a text document. On a fresh Windows install the extensions of known file types are hidden by default. Go to Organize -> Folder and search options -> View -> Uncheck Hide extensions for known file types. Then rename `bitcoin.conf.txt` to `bitcoin.conf`. Now you have a CONF file.