# VPS with 80 GB Space, can't download the whole blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, pruning

I am using an application and WordPress that allows people to pay with Bitcoin in a small multi vendor marketplace for trading hobby items.

The plugin that I'm using is recommending that I run a full Bitcoin node? I don't think I need to, but how does someone do that with a small SSD?

Can you prune and simultaneously download? Is there a blockchain light I don't know about.

I don't want to be running a $60 vps just because of the chain

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pruning will reduce disk space needs to a few GB.  The whole block chain will still be downloaded (which may cost you something in bandwidth charges), but old blocks will be discarded as you go.

See [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/how-can-i-run-bitcoind-in-pruning-mode)