# Error: Prune mode is incompatible with -txindex

Tags: full-node

How do i remove this prune mode??

Comment: Do you know how to find your bitcoin.conf?

Answer (score 2):

I want to add more details on this problem, with the actual hype of Bitcoin there are a lot of people that make bad tutorials with copy and paste on the web, and this causes a lot of confusion.

My additional explanation that I want to add to the [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/101996/91194) is the motivation that this error happens.

The pruning mode is the unique mode to store only the partial data of Bitcoin blockchain, you can find the data stored from Bitcoin core on the directory `path/bitcoin/blocks` by default the `path/bitcoin` si in the home directory and the name of it is `.bitcoin`.

When you use the `-txindex` you are telling the Bitcoin core to be ready to receive any type of query with RPC commands. If you want to use Bitcoin core as a normal wallet you can avoid the option `-txindex`.

The options `-txindex` and `prune=XXX` are mutually exclusive, this means that can not stay together in the same configuration, because you are telling the Bitcoin core to be ready for any type of query but you are also telling that you don't want that  Bitcoin core store a lot of data on you PC. With partial data `-txindex` can not work.

P.S.: Noted also that if you remove the option `prune=XXX`, you need to re-scan the entire blockchain, and also the space on the disk required is very large.

Comment: I don't agree, I might want to see every tx-es (not only the ones meant for me), but I don't need the old ones. Like a detailed short history. So there is definitely a usecase for it.

Answer (score 2):

add this to bitcoin.conf
prune=0 txindex=1 reindex=1 ( this will start to download the entire blockchain again if you have already downloaded it before). Ignore this line if you're going to run the core for the first time. If you use this code to reindex the blockchain then make sure to remove it later on when the reindexing is done.

Good luck

p.s.: i copied that from another forum. but it worked :)

after it started you can already remove reindex, as the change starts after reboot

Answer (score 1):

> **How do i remove this prune mode?**

There is [documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0#wallet-pruning) which says

> To enable block pruning set prune=<N> on the command line or in bitcoin.conf, where N is > the number of MiB to allot for raw block & undo data.
>
> A value of 0 disables pruning. The minimal value above 0 is 550.

---

Related

- [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/13866)