# Remote node to check wallet.dat

Tags: full-node

I don't have enough disk space to download 500GB full node. I want to check my old wallet.dat balance. Is there any free public remote full-node available to check my wallet.dat?

Comment: There is a network of free public remote full nodes available to download valid blocks from. You want to download blocks from them, you don't want to send them your wallet.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the node in [pruning mode](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406). It will then process the entire blockchain but discard old block data after processing it. This will reduce the required disk space to ~10 GiB, but maintain the security and privacy of your wallet.

You could also open the wallet in a fresh install of Bitcoin Core configured with `-maxconnections=0` to prevent it from downloading the blockchain. It should still show you the latest state of the wallet in the GUI, from how far the node was synchronized when you made the backup. You could then use the listed receive addresses to look up on a block explorer whether the funds have meanwhile been spent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is all about my download. My question is how can I check the balance in my wallet.dat file by accessing the remote public server without download. In bitcoincore how to get balance of a wallet.dat on free public node?

Comment: No, you cannot load your wallet.dat into public nodes, they do not offer such a function, as it would defeat their purpose. Your options are either running a node  yourself, or dumping all addresses from it and looking those up or importing them into more lightweight wallet software (and accepting the privacy loss that entails).

Comment: Thank you lot reply right answer of my query